# 4 thread groups in 1 test plan login time for 100 threads in all thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I have included 4 Thread groups in one test plan and recorded script for all thread groups . As all ALL thread groups contain login script , so can i record time for first request of login from all the thread groups ? and then another 4 users entering system and login again and time is recorded -> this i have to do for 100 threads :::: first 4 users come then other 4 come and perform login .please tell if anyone could solve my issue .

Answer (score 0):

If I got your scenario right you need to go for the following configuration:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (Number of Threads: `4`, Loop Count: `25`)

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which performs login

    - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) (Number of Simulated Users to Group By: `4`)

This way you will have 100 requests in total, there will be 25 "login" loops when 4 virtual users will perform login at exactly the same moment.